# How to retrieve subproperty of a data property in OWL API 4.0

Tags: eclipse, java-7, owl-api

I am using owl api 4.0 and the following code will give me all the property of individuals belonging to class Animal.

```
OWLClass animalCl = df.getOWLClass(IRI.create(ontologyIRI + "Animal"));
NodeSet<OWLNamedIndividual> animalIndl = reasoner.getInstances(animalCl, false);

for (OWLNamedIndividual animalNamedIndl : animalIndl.getFlattened())
 {
 Set<OWLDataPropertyAssertionAxiom> propAll=    myontology.getDataPropertyAssertionAxioms(animalNamedIndl);  
 for (OWLDataPropertyAssertionAxiom ax: propAll)   
   {
     for (OWLLiteral propertyLit :  EntitySearcher.getDataPropertyValues(animalNamedIndl, ax.getProperty(), myontolgoy))
     System.out.println("The property " + ax.getProperty() + "has value" + propertyLit);  
      }  
}
```

I have a subproperty "propWt" for every data property. I have used following code:-

```
NodeSet<OWLDataProperty> properties = reasoner.getSubDataProperties((OWLDataProperty) ax.getProperty(), false);
for (OWLDataProperty mysubproperty : properties.getFlattened())
    {
     System.out.println("the sub property is " + mysubproperty);
    }
```

instead of

```
the sub property is <http://localhost:3030/BiOnt.owl#propWt>
```

i get

```
 the sub property is owl:bottomDataProperty
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a reasoner for the ontology, I assume you want all subproperties, either asserted or inferred.
The reasoner can do the job:

```
NodeSet<OWLDataProperty> properties = reasoner.getSubDataProperties(property, false);
```

Comment: I used this code and have amended my question accordingly with now-issue

Comment: Can you show the ontology, or a fragment reproducing the issue, and the reasoner you're using? The owlapi side looks fine, could be a reasoner bug or a problem with the ontology.

Comment: ok. my bad i could retrieve the sub property. this owlbottomDataProperty is displayed for the properties whose subproperty is not defined. Your answer was indeed correct :)